# undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, haml, simple-form

There is a controller of messages:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_chat

  def index
    @messages = @chat.messages
  end

  def create
    @message = @chat.messages.build(params[:message])
    if @message.save
      redirect_to @chat, notice: "Message sent"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

    def load_chat
      @chat = Chat.find(params[:chat_id])
    end

end
```

Here is my view file:

```
%h1 = @chat.name

= content_tag :div, id: 'messages', data: {url: chat_messages_path(@chat)} do
  = render @chat.messages


%h2 New message

= render 'messages/form'
```

Here is my messages/form:

```
= simple_form_for @message do |f|
  = f.input :text
  = f.submit 'Send message', class: 'btn btn-success'
```

And finally my routes.rb file:

```
resources :chats, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create] do
      resources :messages
end
```

So the problem is that I get an error that is `undefined method model_name for nil:NilClass` when I open chats/show link because there is rendering a form of new message. I tried to replace `@message` with `Message.new` that does not do the job, still the same problem. I tried also remove `resources :messages` outside `resources :chats`, that did a trick, but it isn't correct because chats has many messages and messages belongs to chat. Do you have any idea how this form should work for me?

Edit: Chats controller:

```
class ChatsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_chat, :authenticate_user!


  def index
    @chats = current_user.chats
  end

  def show
    @chat = current_user.chats.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @chat = current_user.chats.new
  end

  def create
    @chat = current_user.chats.new chat_params
    if @chat.save
      flash[:notice] = 'chat asked'
      redirect_to chats_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
    @chat.destroy!
    flash[:notice] = 'chat deleted'
    redirect_to chats_path
  end

  def update
    if @chat.update_attributes chat_params
      flash[:notice] = 'chat saved'
      redirect_to chat_path
    else
      redirect_to edit_chat_path(@chat)
    end
  end

  private
    def chat_params
      params.require(:chat).permit :name, :user_id
    end

    def find_chat
      @chat = current_user.chats.find(params[:id]) if params[:id]
    end
end
```

And there is my error log:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass):
    1: = simple_form_for @message do |f|
    2:   = f.input :text
    3:   = f.submit 'Send message', class: 'btn btn-success' 
    4:      app/views/messages/_form.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_messages__form_html_haml___2629708334715527453_82911540'   app/views/chats/show.html.haml:9:in `_app_views_chats_show_html_haml__2381438814653998256_88403540'


  Rendered /home/titas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (10.9ms)   Rendered /home/titas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (3.9ms)   Rendered /home/titas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (3.2ms)   Rendered /home/titas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (35.7ms)   Rendered /home/titas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.6ms)   Rendered /home/titas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)   Rendered /home/titas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)   Rendered /home/titas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.9ms)   Rendered /home/titas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (23.0ms)   Rendered /home/titas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.5ms)   Rendered /home/titas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.5ms)   Rendered /home/titas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (42.8ms)
```

Comment: Please post the source code of `ChatsController`, and your error log.

Comment: @Aetherus updated :)

Comment: Change @chat.messages.build(params[:message]) to @chat.messages.new(params[:message]) and simple_form_for @message do |f| to simple_form_for :message, url: your url do |f|

Answer (score 0):

Could not see where you're declaring `@message`?

--

The error would appear to come from:

```
= render 'messages/form'
```

... which has:

```
= simple_form_for @message do |f|
```

--

Apart from it being bad practice to use `@instance_variables` in partials, in this instance you'll need to declare `@message` explicitly for it to be recognized.

I actually think you could fix the problem by passing the nested resource to your `messages/form` partial:

```
#app/views/messages/_form.html.erb
= simple_form_for [@chat, @chat.messages.new] do |f|
```

*(By the way, all `nilClass` errors basically mean you've referenced a variable which hasn't been declared)*